# Why is my furnace blowing hot air outside through a PVC pipe?

Tags: hvac, heating

I turned on my furnace and went outside and noticed hot air blowing out a J-shaped PVC pipe. Is it a vent or error that needs to be plugged?

Comment: So hot that you cant hold your hand over it?!?! It is going straight out into the atmosphere. That is what mine is doing... It doesn't seem correct.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but to answer your question, all exhaust from a furnace is really hot. High-efficiency ones will just be 'less hot'.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't mean to mark it as an answer... 

It is marked as HE on the side and it has an exhaust vent that is literally so hot that i can only stand to put my hand over it for about 5 seconds before it starts to hurt..

Comment: while that's hot, it's likely not nearly as hot as your standard exhaust flu temperatures, which can burn you almost instantly.

Comment: So I am worrying over nothing?! Just seems to be such a waste of heat...

Comment: If you're worried, it wouldn't hurt to have a furnace tech come out and do a standard check up on things. They could tell you how efficient your model is as well.

Comment: Is there a chance of squirrels or chipmucks getting into the outside pipes during the summer?

Answer (score 7):

It's a high efficiency gas furnace, and that's the exhaust vent. **DO NOT** cover or plug it!

A normal furnace relies on the [stack effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect), to carry hot exhaust up and out of the building. Since high efficiency furnaces extract most of the heat from the exhaust, the exhaust must be forced out. Since it takes less energy to move the cooled exhaust horizontally, HE furnaces typically exhaust to the side of a building rather than the top. As the gases are cooler, PVC, CPVC, or ABS piping can be used to carry the exhaust to the outside.

In a normal furnace you'll typically only see one motor and fan (blower), which is used to draw in cool air and blow warm air throughout the house. In an HE furnace you'll also find a draft inducer or purge motor and fan, which is used to draw in combustion air and push out exhaust.

Comment: OP mentions hot air blowing out (and I see the same thing with mine). Does this indicate that heat extraction is less than optimal?

Comment: @alt No.  There will be some heat left in the exhaust, unless the furnace is 100% efficient.

Comment: In the "old days" the combustion exhaust was so hot we ran them via metal ducts and up chimney flues...  These new fangled HE furnaces are cool enough to only require PVC.